# How to createSpyObj in Angular using jest js?

Tags: angular, jestjs, angular10

I am using jest for Angular testing.

In my scenario I have to test child component from parent. here I am accessing child component methods and properties  using @viewchild in parent componet

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

    @Component({
        template: `<div><\div>`
    })
    export class ChildComponent {
    
        public childMethod() {
            ...
        }
    }


import { Component, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { ChildComponent } from 'child.component';

@Component({
    template: ``
})
export class ParentComponent {

    @ViewChild('child')
    public child: ChildComponent;

    public parentMethod() {
        this.child.childMethod();
    }
}
```

In jasmin we can do using createspyobj

jasmin

```
const childComponent = jasmine.createSpyObj('ChildComponent', ['childMethod']);
it('should invoke childMethod when parentMethod is invoked', () => {
        component.childComponent =  childComponent;
        component.parentMethod();
        expect(childComponent.childMethod).toHaveBeenCalled();
    });
```

(exactly I want this
How to to same in **jest**. I did not find anything . How to spy child component

Can any one please tell.

Thanks in advance

Comment: The post you have linked to shows a contrived example of how unit testing shouldn't be done. It tests arbitrary implementation details and doesn't offer any value (an extremely common problem). Post the code that you're dealing with, and describe what you are trying to test. Otherwise you'll end up with an answer that will help you write a low value, maintenance heavy, unit test. [ng-mocks](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng-mocks) should be high on your list of utilities when working with angular.

Comment: @Adam please find updated post..

Comment: That's not your code. Answering the question as asked will likely result in a very low value unit test being written, I want to direct you how to write a good unit test, as it's a surprisingly rare ability. If you could update it with your actual component code (the relevant parts) and describe what you want to test, I can help your out.

Comment: In general, in Angular, things happen by changing inputs or emitting events from outputs. Those are (again, generally) the only things you should be doing in a unit test (for a component) - setting (or mocking) inputs and emitting from outputs and testing the resultant behavior. Calling methods directly is usually a sign of testing an implementation detail and results in a meaningless (or low value) and brittle test.

Comment: There is number of ways to communicate parent and child in angular,, Angular framwork providing fequture of @viewchild of component, then how you say it brittle test, If you dont want answer requesting you to dont argue,, Now I clearly specify what Exactly I want,

Comment: The test is brittle because it relies on the implementation. This means that if the implementation changes in a way that wouldn't break real components, the test breaks any way and needs to be fixed. Not necessarily a bad thing, just a matter of fact.

Comment: @EstusFlask tests that break when the application isn't broken are of negative value - they tell you nothing (they are not tied to the application's ability to run as designed or not) but (if you're using CI) still require your time.

Comment: @Adam And it's way, way better than a test that isn't specific enough about what it tests doesn't break when it should. It tells that the implementation that a test tests has been changed and needs to be revisited. In case the fail is valid, this makes debugging much easier. If it takes too much efforts to maintain, it's bad, otherwise it's good, and this depends a lot on a project. What you're discussing is whitebox vs blackbox testing. I see too often that people consider this a religion and preach. Please, don't. All testing approaches have their good and bad uses.

Comment: @EstusFlask - instead of continuing this, I'll just say that your first sentence is one heck of a strawman - of course an implementation test is better than an invalid test (i.e. one that `doesn't break when it should`), but that doesn't mean it's a sane testing approach.

Comment: https://kentcdodds.com/blog/testing-implementation-details

Answer (score 0):

Jest doesn't have this utility function. It needs to be written manually, also this way it can provide type safety if needed that Jasmine `createSpyObj` can't have by design:

```
const mockChildComponent: ChildComponent = {
  childMethod: jest.fn(...)
}
```

There are auto-mock features to provide dummy mock objects for existing modules that provide the same functionality, although this may give unexpected results because of undocumented magic behind them:

```
const { ChildComponent: MockChildComponent } = jest.createMockFromModule('child.component')
mockChildComponent = new MockChildComponent()
```